# Jest does wait for promise to resolve

Tags: javascript, jestjs

[Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous) says:

> You can also use the .resolves matcher in your expect statement, and
>   Jest **will wait for that promise to resolve**. If the promise is
>   rejected, the test will automatically fail. If you expect a promise to
>   be rejected, use the .rejects matcher. It works analogically to the
>   .resolves matcher. If the promise is fulfilled, the test will
>   automatically fail.

This is my code:

```
body = {
        currentPassword: "WrongPassword",
        newPassword: "UglyPassword",
};
expect(api(`users/${userId}/password`, { method: 'PATCH', json: body, headers: getAuthHeader(jwtData) })).rejects.toThrow();

body.currentPassword = "BadPassword";
```

The test fails because the password sent to the endpoint is "BadPassword". The documentation says that Jest WILL WAIT for promise which is not true. How can I make it wait? The test is not deterministic now.

Comment: you forgot to put await. Just put await before api it will resolve your error.

Comment: test('the fetch fails with an error', async () => {
  await expect(fetchData()).rejects.toThrow('error');
});

Comment: I used this approach originally but then JEST was not able to catch the error. See this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61214808/1639556

Comment: Did you try to use native promise rather than async await.? Can you please try?

Comment: async function callUser(){
    return api(`users/${userId}/password`, { 
      method: 'PATCH', 
      json: body, 
      headers: getAuthHeader(jwtData) 
    });
}
expect(await callUser()).rejects.toThrow();

Comment: I am back to yesterday trouble with HTTPError: Response code 403 (Forbidden) not caught

Comment: ok, the only workaround is to tell GotJS not to throw exceptions'

Comment: I think you should use this way.. can you try ? http://dpaste.com/3HXGAZ2

Comment: you see this test code and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211743/discussion-between-leos-literak-and-dipak-chavda).